# Why my package can't be installed with "pipx"?

Tags: python, pip, setup.py, pypi

I've got a Python project [aws-ssm-tools](https://github.com/mludvig/aws-ssm-tools) that uses `setup.py` for packaging. It comes with 3 scripts: `ssm-tunnel`, `ssm-session` and `ssm-copy`.

It can be installed with `pip install aws-ssm-tools` and puts the scripts to `~/.local/bin/`.

However when I try to install it with `pipx` it fails:

```sh
~ $ pipx install aws-ssm-tools

No apps associated with package aws-ssm-tools. Try again with '--include-deps' 
to include apps of dependent packages, which are listed above. If you are 
attempting to install a library, pipx should not be used. Consider using pip or 
a similar tool instead.
```

I have the scripts specified in [`setup.py`](https://github.com/mludvig/aws-ssm-tools/blob/master/setup.py):

```py
SCRIPTS = [
    'ssm-session',
    'ssm-copy',
    'ssm-tunnel',
    'ssm-tunnel-updown.dns-example',
]

# ...

setup(
    name="aws-ssm-tools",
    version=VERSION,
    packages=find_packages(),
    scripts=SCRIPTS+[
        'ssm-tunnel-agent'
    ],
    # ...
)
```

What else do I have to do to make `pipx` happy?

Comment: Why do you need to use pipx? It already stated that "If you are 
attempting to install a library, pipx should not be used. Consider using pip or 
a similar tool instead."

Comment: @HùngNguyễn because it's not a library, it's a command line tool. I prefer to use `pipx` for installing such packages. Same as for example to install `ansible` or `awscli` - these also provide cli tools and can be installed with `pipx`.

Comment: Have you read aws-ssm-tools installation documents? I found out that it can only be installed with pip, not pipx. https://pypi.org/project/aws-ssm-tools/

Comment: @HùngNguyễn I actually wrote it, it’s *my* project :) I’m asking here because I want to make it pipx-compatible :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated in the [*pipx* documentation chapter "How pipx works", section "Developing for pix"](https://pipxproject.github.io/pipx/how-pipx-works/#developing-for-pipx), the project requires [*setuptools* `entry_points`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation).

According to the content of your question, it seems that the target project uses `scripts`, they are similar in purpose to `entry-points` but *pipx* does not look for those and does not expose them.